# Definition of unit in Modelica (OpenModelica) for parameters, cannot be found in scope of parameters file

Tags: unit-testing, parameters, modelica, ubuntu-18.04, openmodelica

I'm new in Modelica programming (I'm using OpenModelica and text editor on Ubuntu 1.8), and I have to define some units, one of these is min^(-1), and I did it writing " type min_1=Real(unit="min^(-1)"); " in a model file with .mo extension (in this file I have no equations, I have only units definitions), and in another Modelica file (a record file) I have only parameters definitions (no equations) e.g. parameter min_1 beta=0.002; , but when I run the entire model I have an error concerning only (at least apparently, because I have no other erros) this particular unit, beacuse it says that min_1 is not found the scope of the file that cointains only parameters definitions (but min_1 is present is this file, in fact, apparently, I don't have the same problem with other units I defined), so I am not able to understand what is the real problem with that beacuse the error is really vague. Before I tryed to define units, all parameters were defined as Real, and the model plotted perfectly, so I'm pretty sure that the only possible problem is located in these 2 files. (Naturally all Modelica files of my entire Model are located in the same folder).

To define my units file I wrote in a .mo file (a model file):

```
model def_units
type dlkg=Real(unit="dl/kg");
type mg_1=Real(unit="mg^(-1)");
type kg_1=Real(unit="1/kg");
type min_kg_pmol=Real(unit="min*kg/pmol");
type min_1=Real(unit="min^(-1)");
type mg_kg_min=Real(unit="mg/kg/min");
type mg_kg_min_pmol_l=Real(unit="mg/kg/min*pmol*l");
type mg_kg_min_pmol_kg=Real(unit="mg/kg/min*pmol*kg");
type mg_kg=Real(unit="mg/kg");
type pmol_kg_mg_dl=Real(unit="pmol/kg*(mg/dl)");
type pmol_kg_min_dl=Real(unit="pmol/kg*(min/dl)");
end def_units;
```

To define my parameters I wrote in a separate .mo file (a record file) this:

```
record param
parameter min_1 alpha=0.001 ;
parameter min_1 beta=0.002;
parameter dl_kg gamma=0.003;
parameter mg_kg_min delta=0.004;
/* [... ] */
/* many other parameters defined in this way */
/* [... ] */
end param;
```

I did not use/import any libraries, those are standard units of the International System, they are only kinda "concatenated" between them, and reading on Internet the only way I found to define something more specific, like in this case, was the way I wrote my code above (my supervisor also approved the way I defined my units).

What could be the problem in this case?

Please if you can, try to explain in a simply and specific way.

Any help and advice will be very appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working fine, but you need to import def_units elements in your param record or you need to define them as `parameter def_units.min_1 beta=0.002;`
I would also suggest changing def_units from a model to a package.
Read more about Modelica imports and different Modelica classes such as packages, records, models and blocks in the Modelica Specification on modelica.org or the Modelica Book: http://book.xogeny.com/.

File def_units.mo

```
model def_units
  type dl_kg=Real(unit="dl/kg");
  type mg_1=Real(unit="mg^(-1)");
  type kg_1=Real(unit="1/kg");
  type min_kg_pmol=Real(unit="min*kg/pmol");
  type min_1=Real(unit="min^(-1)");
  type mg_kg_min=Real(unit="mg/kg/min");
  type mg_kg_min_pmol_l=Real(unit="mg/kg/min*pmol*l");
  type mg_kg_min_pmol_kg=Real(unit="mg/kg/min*pmol*kg");
  type mg_kg=Real(unit="mg/kg");
  type pmol_kg_mg_dl=Real(unit="pmol/kg*(mg/dl)");
  type pmol_kg_min_dl=Real(unit="pmol/kg*(min/dl)");
end def_units;
```

File param.mo

```
record param
  import def_units.*; // you need to import all definitions from def_units!
  parameter min_1 alpha=0.001 ;
  parameter min_1 beta=0.002;
  parameter dl_kg gamma=0.003;
  parameter mg_kg_min delta=0.004;
  /* [... ] */
  /* many other parameters defined in this way */
  /* [... ] */
end param;
```

File script t.mos

```
loadFile("def_units.mo"); getErrorString();
loadFile("param.mo"); getErrorString();
instantiateModel(param); getErrorString();
```

Running the script with the OpenModelica compiler OMC:

```
adrpo33@ida-0030 MINGW64 /c/home/adrpo33/dev/OMTesting/bugs/units
$ ~/dev/OpenModelica/build/bin/omc t.mos
true
""
true
""
"class param
  parameter Real alpha(unit = \"min^(-1)\") = 0.001;
  parameter Real beta(unit = \"min^(-1)\") = 0.002;
  parameter Real gamma(unit = \"dl/kg\") = 0.003;
  parameter Real delta(unit = \"mg/kg/min\") = 0.004;
end param;
"
""
```